# Trim dentro de select anidado

Tags: php, mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Estoy insertando una consulta, donde uno de los valores viene con un `SELECT`, pero tengo el problema que el valor que va dentro del `WHERE` tiene espacios, con lo que necesito quitarlos
He probado con TRIM pero con consigo que funcione bien

```
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_CONDITION_RATE (CUSTOMER_ID, PRODUCT_CODE)
VALUES(
    (SELECT `ID` FROM CUSTOMER WHERE `CODE` = TRIM("    C000000 ")), 
    "PF0001_01", 
  );
```

Comment: Es que no tienes exactamente espacios en blanco, tienes otra cosa. ¿Has probado con `REPLACE("  C000000 ",' ','')` usando lo que sea que es ese caracter?

Comment: Correcto, esa es la solucion

Answer (score 0):

Intenta usando LTRIM y RTRIM uno después del otro, LTRIM elimina los espacios de la izquierda y RTRIM de la derecha.

```
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_CONDITION_RATE (CUSTOMER_ID, PRODUCT_CODE)
VALUES((SELECT `ID` FROM CUSTOMER WHERE `CODE` = RTRIM(LTRIM('    C000000 '))),'PF0001_01',);
```